# how can cut some part of div crank

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVMD.png)

i want to design slider like this picture .i have its slider with carousel bootstrap,how can i cut div crank and set another div beside it?

this is my code for slider that used bootstrap class

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

 
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000/ffffff/" alt="..." >
    </div>
  <div class="item">
      <img  class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffff00/ffffff/" alt="..." >
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cut div crank"?

Comment: @Zze i mean like the picture the slider is not smooth

Comment: @Zze i mean Diagonal

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now, and so how do you want the carousel to work? both images change? or what happens?

Answer (score 0):

look at this link [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html) if I understood you correctly is this Plugin